# Get text and numbers

Tags: php, regex

I have the following strings:

```
Some random 516 text100.
text3.
```

How could I programmatically obtain something like:

```
$a[0]["text"] = Some random 516 text
$a[0]["id"] = 100

$a[1]["text"] = text
$a[1]["id"] = 3
```

Thanks

Comment: It's too bad you don't have "Some random 516 text,100" and "text,3"! Then it would just be splitting the string on that.

Comment: it's always ending with "text{NumberID}" ? if so , then it can be done , let me know

Comment: Can you use a delimiter like @GlaciesofPacis brought up? Otherwise, you'd have to use a regular expression...

Comment: @RedhopIT From his examples, it looks like `text{number}.` (notice period at end)

Comment: Must the "." at the end of the string be taken into account ? So you want to separate the last numbers before the dot, and the preceding text ? a `/(.*)(\d+)\./` should be okay (then use $1 and $2)

Comment: The other thing I'm wondering is if the text part can end with a number. If it can, then it would be impossible to tell which part of the ID is actually part of the text part.

Comment: What @Orabîg wrote should lead you to the solution ;)

Comment: Indeed there always is the dot at the end. I forgot to mention

Comment: Thanks @RedhopIT, however, there was a mistake in my regexp. Solution's below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works :

```
$input = array("Some random 516 text100.",
        "text3.");

$output=array();

foreach ($input as $text) {
    preg_match('/(.*?)(\d+)\./',$text,$match);
    array_shift($match); // removes first element
    array_push($output,$match);
}

print_r($output);
```

outputs :

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Some random 516 text
            [1] => 100
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => text
            [1] => 3
        )

)
```

Answer (score 2):

If your input is this regular you can use a regexps.

*note:* this version requires a `.` under the `text<number>` part, you might need to tweak this depending on your input:

```
$in='Some random 516 text100.
text3.';

preg_match_all('/^(?<text>.*?text)(?<id>\d+)\./im', $in, $m);
$out = array();
foreach ($m['id'] as $i => $id) {
    $out[] = array('id' => $id, 'text' => $m['text'][$i]);
}
var_export($out);
```

The foreach massage the results into the requested format, you might not need that if you can use the one `preg_match_all()` returns originally.